# SQL Server LocalDB Instance; error restoring backup (MasterDBPath not available)

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2012 Local DB Installed, and am connecting to it via (localdb)\v11.0.

When trying to restore a backup file, I get:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Property MasterDBPath is not available for Information
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information'. This property may
>   not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to
>   insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60+((SQL11_RTM).120210-1846+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.PropertyCannotBeRetrievedExceptionText&EvtID=MasterDBPath&LinkId=20476

I have tried setting MasterDBPath string value in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion`
```

but this hasn't helped.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: What is the source SQL Server edition and version of the backup file?

Comment: The backup is from a SQL Server 2012 Developer edition install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a proper solution, but this error does not occur if you create a blank database, then restore your backup overwriting the blank database.

Or you can use the restore T-SQL commands:

```
RESTORE DATABASE <database> FROM DISK = '<backupfile>' WITH NORECOVERY,
    MOVE 'example_dat' TO 'C:\Temp\<database>.mdf',
    MOVE 'example_log' TO 'C:\Temp\<database>.ldf'
```

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, and solved it.

You need to add 2 strings in the Windows Registry via `regedit.exe` at 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer`:

```
DefaultData
DefaultLog
```

For me, their values are both `C:\Users\neil\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0`.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me running as administrator however I did also have to create a third key `BackupDirectory` which I pointed to a similar directory.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was fixed after I installed the newest Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017.