# Move folder of SQL Server LocalDB instances from the default location

Tags: ssms, sql-server-express, sql-server-localdb

I get multiple errors with `LocalDB` ([startup error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30383/cannot-start-sqllocaldb-instance-with-my-windows-account), [can't create DB from SQL Server Management Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20130827221618/http://www.stratospher.es:80/blog/post/error-creating-database-in-localdb-using-sql-server-management-studio-2012-ssms) and also [multiple](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ba6d023-5899-4c5a-9270-87792840a3ba/insufficient-access-rights-error-when-doing-backup?forum=sqlsmoanddmo) [issues](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23609/sql-server-localdb-instance-error-restoring-backup-masterdbpath-not-available) when trying to restore a backup) and none of the fixes I found are helping anything. It seems to me that all errors have their root in permissions not set up correctly.

Now a simple DDL table creation script works fine from SQL Server Management Studio and creates the database in the root of my user account's folder ([as explained here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151207060704/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx)). The Instances folder however (located at `D:\Users\[My name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances` despite when installing the [SQL Server Express with Advanced Services](https://web.archive.org/web/20200906111909/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) I specified the DATA folder in another location - where only standard SQL Server Express `.mdf` files are stored, but not `LocalDB` instances) seems problematic regarding permissions (in contrary to the account root) therefore and also for having my DB files in a location among my projects I'd like to move the Instances folder to another place. Is this possible? I haven't even found a corresponding registry entry.

I'm using SQL Server Express 2012 and also SSMS of the same version (latest updates installed).

---

The Database Settings page threw an error for me, not being able to edit nor see any configuration there. I let Windows Update check for updates again and there were some updates for SQL Server Express that weren't installed (although I'm sure I selected everything to install before), so I installed them. This made it possible for me to go to the settings page.

I've tried to set up the LocalDB instance's root folder to somewhere else but I get an access denied error for every folder I tried, namely

> Alter failed for Settings
> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ObjectKeyBase'.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
> batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> RegCreateKeyEx() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.' (Microsoft SQL
> Server, Error: 22002)

I get this even if the folder has Full control set for Everyone! Even more amusing the only folder that works, one that is set as a default (the user account's root) has no special permissions applied - just the ones my user has (just as any other folder I tried to set). In effect this means that all my LocalDB databases' files are saved to my account's root folder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I used Process Monitor to trace the registry access and found it was getting an Access Denied while trying to write:

```
3:16:40.8405491 PM  
sqlservr.exe 8756   
RegCreateKey    
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer   
ACCESS DENIED   
Desired Access: Write
```

I got around this by opening the Registry Editor and giving *Everyone* full access to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer`. Then I changed the default location and removed the Everyone access once it was done. This made the following extra keys that weren't there before:

- DefaultData
- DefaultLog
- BackupDirectory